# icons and images are not showing after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, publish

Hi I have published and deploy a asp.net MVC 5 application on IIS. On local machine everything was working fine but on server ICONS and images are not showing, just a small square box is there.
Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked many, many, *many* times over. Have you done any research or troubleshooting  at this point? If so, what?

Comment: Show your code so we can help you.

Comment: yes i have searched google and stackoverflow also, but unable to resolve.

Comment: this is the bundleConfig Code:

Comment: // Font Awesome icons style
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/font-awesome/css").Include(
                      "~/Vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));

Comment: @Guri That should be an edit to your question - comments can and will be removed automatically at any time. That being said, where is your /fonts directory in relation to the path you're trying to load? What errors, if any, are displayed in the developer console? You commented that you've searched for existing answers, so what have you tried? It's expected that you would include links to other questions, if you've tried something else already. If you haven't yet, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

during the published PNG files were missing,